# What does the notation $\mathcal{F} \subset 2^{[n]}$ mean?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What does the highlighted notation mean?

> **Theorem 1.** *Let $\color{red}{\mathcal{F} \subset 2^{[n]}}$ be such that $|A|$ is odd for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $|A \cap B|$ is even for every distinct $A,B\in \mathcal{F}$. Then $|\mathcal{F}| \le n$.*

Comment: $[n]$ probably means some set with $n$ elements, and it doesn't matter which, so for example $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.   $2^{[n]}$ is the power set of this set.  So $\mathcal F$ here is just some family of sets with elements from $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.   $

Comment: That image makes it look like you typset a Latex document just for this question alone. Did you know you can use Latex code natively on the site? Just enclose Latex code with `$`s for inline maths, or with `$$` for display maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these can sometimes mean other things depending on who is writing, but usually:

- $[n]$ means $\{1,\dots,n\}$ (other authors might define this as $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ instead)
- $2^A$ where $A$ is a set means $\{S : S \subseteq A\}$ (powerset)
- also $\binom{A}{k} = \{S : S \subseteq A \text{ and } |S| = k\}$ and $X^Y$ is the set of all functions $Y \to X$
- also $\subset$ likely means $\subseteq$ (some people use this convention but I'm not a fan)